# How can i check file name form is number by batch file?

Tags: batch-file

there are some of folder, how can i check the file folder or file name compose of number?

if the file folder or file name like `1123456` and show "successful"; if the file folder or file name like `asd2334` and show "Fail".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*$"` could give false positives for some non-numeric characters. Why? Read a complete list of all characters supported by FINDSTR, sorted in the collation sequence used by FINDSTR to establish regex character class ranges in [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159191/3439404). Examples for different code pages:

> ```
> ==> chcp 852>NUL
>
> ==> echo řźČ|findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*$"
> řźČ
>
> ==> chcp 850>NUL
>
> ==> echo ²½¼|findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*$"
> ²½¼
>
> ==> chcp 737>NUL
>
> ==> echo ²τυ|findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*$"
> ²τυ
>
> ==>
> ```

Complex script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_folder=D:\test\SO\45729489"
pushd "%_folder%"
echo(
echo ### false positives from `findstr`:
for %%G in (*) do (
    echo %%~nG|findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*$" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo findstr NoNumeric %%~G
    ) else (
        echo findstr numerical %%~G
    )
)
echo(
echo === right way: `for /F "delims=0123456789"`
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('2^>NUL dir /B') do (
    set "_NoNumber="
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%g in ("%%~nG") do set "_NoNumber=%%~g"
    if defined _NoNumber (
        echo for /F  NoNumeric %%~G
    ) else (
        echo for /F  numerical %%~G
    )
)
popd
```

**Output** (run in `CHCP 852` scope):

> ```
> ==> D:\bat\SO\a45729489.bat
>
> ### false positives from `findstr`:
> findstr numerical 457294890.txt
> findstr NoNumeric 45729489A.txt
> findstr numerical 45729489Č.txt
> findstr numerical 45729489ř.txt
> findstr numerical 45729489ź.txt
>
> === right way: `for /F "delims=0123456789"`
> for /F  numerical 457294890.txt
> for /F  NoNumeric 45729489A.txt
> for /F  NoNumeric 45729489Č.txt
> for /F  NoNumeric 45729489ř.txt
> for /F  NoNumeric 45729489ź.txt
>
> ==>
> ```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~nG` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>NUL`, `2>&1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`^` *Circumflex Accent* in `2^>NUL`)  [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: It will show "裝置未就緒。" (translation from google: The device is not ready.) at the beginning . does i need to do some things?

Comment: Change the `set "_folder=D:\test\SO\45729489"` line to meet your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a for /f with all digits as delimiters.
If nothing is left from the tested var, it is a number.

```
> type IsNumber.cmd
@Echo off
:loop
set "value="
set /p value=input value:
if "%value%" equ "" exit /B
set "test="
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%value%") Do set "test=%%A"
Echo value=%value%^<
echo test =%test%^<
if "%test%" equ "" (echo %value% is a number) else (Echo %value% is not a number)
goto :loop
```

If used as a subroutine returning an errorlevel you can easily incorporate in your batch.

```
@Echo off

For %%A in (1234 one 5a6 456 897) do (
    Call :IsNumber "%%~nA" && (Echo Is  a number: %%A) || (Echo not a number: %%A)
)
Goto :Eof

:IsNumber
Set Ret=0
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%~1") Do set Ret=1
Exit /B %Ret%
```

Sample output:

```
Is  a number: 1234
not a number: one
not a number: 5a6
Is  a number: 456
Is  a number: 897
```

To have a for process dir output you need the `for /f` variant:

```
For /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('Dir /B/AD ') do (
```

Comment: thanks for solution, downer one there is no response after runn, is there any thing i need to do? and Is there can check folder name?

Comment: It just depends on what argument you pass to the sub `:IsNumber` if it isn't a number it will return with errorlevel 1. I'll change 2nd batch to make it clearer.

Comment: Hi i'm change `1234 one 5a6 456 897` to `'dir /b/ad'` to get folder list, but it only get `dir`, `/b/ad`. how can i check folder name?

Comment: I did append a proper for to parse dir output to my answer.

Comment: i try to change `For %%A in (1234 one 5a6 456 897) do (` to `For /f "tokens=" %%A in ('Dir /B/AD ') do (`. But there is no response after running, is there any thing i need to do?

Comment: My fault, it's either `"tokens=*"` or `"delims="`. Commenting from my mobile I mixed them up.

Answer (score 0):

This batch script will loop through `*.txt` files from a directory.
Checks file name if its numberic, it will echo *Successfull*, otherwise *Failed*

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in ("C:\Test\*.txt") do (

echo %%~nf| findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$">nul

if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    echo %%~nf ---------------------------------------------------- Successful
)else (echo %%~nf ---------------------------------------------------- Failed)

)

pause
```

Comment: thanks for solution, it looks like to check file name to number. Is there can check folder name?